GCP Oauth for Android How do I generate access token with refresh token without client secret
I am trying to access gmail api.I have generated access token,id token,refresh token etc,access token expires after every hour.To generate new access token I have refresh token but it seems client secret is required to get new token.but for android application I could get only client id from gcp credentials page.
can anyone guide me regarding this.
I have tried to generate using https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token  .but it gives invalid grant type error.

Edit your question. Show how you generated the refresh token. That usually requires the Client Secret. Explain why you cannot provide the Client Secret at the later step. Otherwise, your option is to repeat the authorization and generate a new access token.
